# Why does numpy.histogram (Python) leave off one element as compared to hist in Matlab?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, histogram

I am trying to convert some Matlab code to Python, and the Matlab code looks like:

```
[N,X] = hist(Isb*1e6, -3:0.01:0)
```

where Isb is a 2048000 element 1D array. N is output as a 301 element 1D array.

My Python code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
N,X = np.histogram(Isb*1e6,np.array(-3,0.01,0.01))
```

but the N Python outputs is a 300 element 1D array where the last element from the Matlab N is left off.

Is there a way to replicate what Matlab does more accurately?

I need N and X to be the same size so that I can do this:

```
loc = X < -0.75
I   = N[loc].argmax()
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that in matlab's `hist(x, vec)`, vec difines the **bin-centers**, while in matlab `histc(x, vec)` vec defines the **bin-edges** of the histogram. Numpy's histogram seems to work with **bin-edges**. Is this difference important to you? It should be easy to convert from one to the other, and you might have to add an extra `Inf` to the end of the bin-edges to get it to return the extra bin you want. More or less like this (untested):

```
import numpy as np

def my_hist(x, bin_centers):
    bin_edges = np.r_[-np.Inf, 0.5 * (bin_centers[:-1] + bin_centers[1:]), 
        np.Inf]
    counts, edges =  np.histogram(x, bin_edges)
    return counts
```

For sure it does not cover all the edge-cases that matlab's `hist` provides, but you get the idea.

Comment: Under the hood `hist` converts everything to edges and calls the native function `histc` anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, in matlab -3:0.01:0 specifies the bin-centers, namely 301.
What your doing in numpy specifies bin-edges, so this will be one bin less than in matlab.

Hence, you could either move from hist to histc within matlab, or make sure you apply the same bin-edges in numpy.
In this special case (equidistant bins) you could also use numpy like this:

```
N,X = np.histogram(x, bins = n_bins, range = (xmin, xmax))
```

In this case: n_bins of 301 and (xmin, xmax) being (-3.005,0.005) should be equivalent to matlab's hist.

See also:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: I need X and N to be the same size, so I can do the following:
`loc = X < -0.75`
`I = N[loc].argmax()`