# Numpy equivalent to MATLAB's hist

Tags: matlab, numpy

For some reason Numpy's hist always returns one less bin than MATLAB's hist:

for example in MATLAB:

```
x = [1,2,2,2,1,4,4,2,3,3,3,3];
[Rep,Val] = hist(x,unique(x));
```

gives:

```
Rep = [2 4 4 2]
Val = [1 2 3 4]
```

but in Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,2,2,1,4,4,2,3,3,3,3])
Rep, Val = np.histogram(x,np.unique(x))
```

gives:

```
>>>Rep
array([2, 4, 6])
>>>Val
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

How can I get identical results ti MATLAB's?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match Matlab hist() with Numpy histogram()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869651/match-matlab-hist-with-numpy-histogram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I want to explain this problem.

In Phyton it is running like:

`np.unique(x)` = [1, 2, 3, 4] so,

- The first bin is equal to [1, 2) (including 1, but excluding 2) and therefore ==> `Rep[0]`=2
- The second bin is equal to [2, 3) (including 2, but excluding 3)  and therefore ==> `Rep[1]`=4
- The last bin is equal to [3, 4], which includes 4. Therefore ==> `Rep[2]` = 6

In MATLAB `hist()` function is running like:

- The first bin is equal to [1, 2) (including 1, but excluding 2) and therefore ==> `Rep[0]`=2
- The second bin is equal to [2, 3) (including 2, but excluding 3)  and therefore ==> `Rep[1]`=4
- The third bin is equal to [3, 4) (including 3, but excluding 4) and therefore ==> `Rep[2]`=4
- The last bin is equal to [4, ∞)  and therefore ==> `Rep[3]`=2

Now If you want same result in Pyhton, you have to use different function in Matlab. This is `histogram()` function. We can decide "bins number".

```
x = [1,2,2,2,1,4,4,2,3,3,3,3];
nbins=3 ;
h= histogram(x,nbins);
h.Values
```

You can see `h.Values` equals to [2,4,6].

I hope, I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on dilayapici's answer on this post, a general solution (applied to your example) to run Python's `np.histogram` in the same way as Matlab's `hist`, is the following:

```
x = np.array([1,2,2,2,1,4,4,2,3,3,3,3])
# Convert the bin centers given in Matlab to bin edges needed in Python.
numBins = len(np.unique(x))
bins = np.linspace(np.amin(x), np.amax(x), numBins)
# Edit the 'bins' argument of `np.histogram` by just putting '+inf' as the last element.
bins = np.concatenate((bins, [np.inf]))
Rep, Val = np.histogram(x, bins)
```

Output:

```
Rep
array([2, 4, 4, 2], dtype=int64)
```