# how is the system of imhist in matlab? what is the equal function with imhist in python?

Tags: python, matlab, histogram

i have code in matlab that use imhist like this

```
intensity = hsi_image(:, :, 3);
[counts , binLocations] = imhist(intensity);
```

the data of intensity is 222x222 double like the image below
[image]

**then i want to know how counts and binLocations are created by the system. because i want to implement it in python**

the 'counts' is 256x1 double like the image below

[image]

and the 'binLocations' is also 256x1 double like the image below

[image]

what i know is that binLocations is in range between 0-1 which devide to 256 values, but **i'm confused about the relation between the input data('intensity') and the binLocations which can output the 'counts' value**

i think it's so different with the histogram in python if using numpy histogram. i try to use it in python like this :

```
counts, binLocations = np.histogram(intensity, bins=256, range=[0,1])
```

the 'counts' is have 256 value like the image below: (which is the shape is same with imhist in matlab, eventhough the result is different)
[image]

but, the 'binLocations' get 257 value like the image below: (which is the shape is different with imhist in matlab)
[image]
[image]

but from what i read from some resources, i get that np.histogram in python give the result of bar histogram and the binLocations is the value of the edge of the bar, so i think that's what cause the binLocations is 256+1 because it is the value of the edge.

then about the 'counts', it count from the data input which is 'intensity' that were in range between 2 edge of binLocations. i think it is make sense about the relation between the data input and the 'counts' that can make a histogram.

**but about the function of 'imhist' in matlab i still don't understand how it works?, how the 'counts' value is get?**
can someone explain about the 'imhist' in matlab? and maybe there is a way to make it in the sameway like matlab in python? because i need to use it in python. thankyou

Comment: This question asks about MATLAB `hist`, not `imhist`, but I think they work more or less the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18065951/7328782

Comment: What is `binLocations(256)` in your MATLAB example? I suspect that it's 0.996. MATLAB uses half open intervals, so the final bin edge is not necessary.