# Why do the indices have 2 differences instead of 1 when using np.histogram instead of histcounts?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, histogram

I want to convert the histcounts in MATLAB to Python. The MATLAB code is:

```
hc=histcounts(data ,Hist_Indx);
```

For this, I have used the np.histogram in Python:

```
hC, bins = np.asarray(np.histogram(data, bins = Hist_Indx), dtype = object)
```

But in the output, the indices in Python are shifted by 2 elements. For example, if in MATLAB the element (95,570) is equal to 5, in Python the element (93,569) is equal to 5.

I know that in MATLAB indices start from one and in Python from zero. Based on this, in the example above, the index in Python should be (94,569), while in the output obtained from the Python code, the index is equal to (93,569).

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: Maybe this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066073/17457846

Comment: First array index in Matlab is 1, first array index in Numpy is 0.

Comment: I know that in MATLAB indices start from one and in Python from zero. Based on this, in the example above, the index in Python should be (94,569), while in the output obtained from the Python code, the index is equal to (93,569).